# Invalid Cast Exception, Database Exception Method, not shared by other coder

Tags: c#

I am working on implementing a new feature in a dashboard application that uses stored procedures to get data from our sister product's SQL Server database.  My coding partner last used the code, and established the new calls, and we have deployed this to production.  I am augmenting what he wrote and adding on to it.

To get started I got the latest version, and updated the Stored Procedure names to match what they are now called in the Database, but when I attempt to utilize them, the helper method to get the data is throwing a System.InvalidCastException.

The code looks as follows:

```
public static Decimal? GetNullibleDecimal(this SqlDataReader reader, int fieldIndex)
{
  object value = reader.GetValue(fieldIndex);
  return value is DBNULL ? null : (Decimal?)value;
}
```

I asked my coding partner to download and try the same changes, and he is not seeing this exception.  We are both running the same versions of the libraries we use from NuGet.  Something is obviously off on my local machine, but I do not know what it could be, or where to look to find it.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Would changing the above snippet to be a conversion rather than a cast resolve this safely?

Thanks in advance,

Andrew S. Giles

Comment: Is your query along the lines of `select *...` or are you selecting specific column names?  It could be that they'e coming back in a different order on your machine, so the Decimal index on your machine is different to his.

Comment: No, I knew enough to not do that.  I think, after some additional review of older code, that some change I made is causing the error... I am reverting now to see if I can find it.

Comment: @DrewGiles Are you absolutely certain that you and he are looking at exactly the same database on exactly the same server? If they are locally hosted, have all SQL scripts been applied to update the schema?